# Which one is better : AbstractTableModel.fireTableDataChanged() or AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowInserted()

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Is it a good idea to add one row and call fireTableRowInserted() or adding all rows and then call fireTableDataChanged()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you do is adding new rows, it's better to add all the rows, and call `fireTableRowsInserted()` with the appropriate first and last rows. The view will have to handle only one event, and the event tells exactly what happens, which avoids refreshing the parts of the view that don't need to be refreshed.

Comment: @D.G. by refreshing whole Model you probably lost all referencies to Custom Renderers and Editors

Comment: @mKorbel no, that is structure changed, no data changed. And it's not probable, but certain for column specific renders/editors for tables where auto create columns from model is true (which is the default)

Comment: I need to fire this after each row addition (and I'm adding a lot of them). Is there a way to avoid calculation of rows number each time?